# In amcharts, is there a way to bring a point forward when you hover over it with your cursor?

Tags: amcharts

I have a category linegraph that I built using a serial amchart. I made it so all the points in a category double in size when the cursor hovers over the category like so:

```
"chartCursor": {
                            "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                            "cursorAlpha": 1,
                            "zoomable": true,
                            "graphBulletSize": 3,
                            "animationDuration": .1,
                            "fullWidth": true,
                            "valueLineAlpha" : .1,
                            "oneBalloonOnly": true
            },
```

The only problem is that if increasing in size makes the bullet overlap with a point further down in the series, the latter point remains on the forefront of the the chart, on top of the enlarged image. This isn't good because I am using custom bullets that actually contain necessary information. My question is: is there a way to temporarily bring a point modified by the cursor to the front of the graph to allow the image to be seen without impediment?

I am aware that I can put the image into a balloon, I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bullets are part of the SVG tree, and, technically there is no way in SVG to set a "z-index" of the element (each subsequent node is drawn on top of the previous ones), the only way to go about it is to manipulate the actual order of bullets on chart on hover.

For that we can use chart cursor's [`changed`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#changed) event:

```
"listeners": [ {
  "event": "changed",
  "method": function( e ) {
    if ( e.index === undefined )
      return;
    for ( var i = 0; i < e.chart.graphs.length; i++ ) {
      // get graph
      var graph = e.chart.graphs[ i ];
      var holder = graph.bulletSet.node;

      // find the bullet and move it
      for ( var x = 0; x < graph.allBullets.length; x++ ) {
        var bullet = graph.allBullets[ x ];
        if ( bullet.graphDataItem.index === e.index ) {
          holder.appendChild( bullet.node );
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
} ]
```

The code above will move the bullets of the category currently being hovered on to the end of their respective containers, so they are drawn on top of any other bullets.

Here's a [working example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/43611645554e924eafabde989eabe4a6).

Comment: This works fine if you have 1 series, but somehow it crashes on the line holder.appendChild( bullet ); saying: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'; when I have multiple series. It works on the first category when it gets selected, but anything beyond that the points' sizes increase, then the error pops up and the entire page freezes.

Comment: Hm, works perfectly fine for me with multiple graphs: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/43611645554e924eafabde989eabe4a6 Maybe you have a greaph without bullets?

Comment: Every graph has at least 1 bullet, but not every category has a bullet for every graph.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That might be a problem. Any chance to share your complete chart code and data so I can experiment with it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have permission to do that. If you have any ideas without my code, I'd love to hear them, otherwise thank you for your time and help all the same.

Comment: Updated my code to work even if no all data points have bullets. The codepen demo in link is updated as well.